# Multiplying two objects

Tags: java

Hey so I will do my best at explaining this (and will have to change some code sorry if it looks weird) so I currently have:

```
public Job(String name, int tickets, double wage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tickets = tickets;
    this.wage = wage;
```

& and getters and setters for these and also making a list here:

```
Job Peter = new Job (name: "Peter",  tickets: 100, wage: 1.55);
        System.out.println(Peter);
```

So my issue is that lets say the **total wage** is calculated by **tickets * wage** how do I go about doing this by automation.

> ***I can do this, however want a simpler method where it is automated so    I can just for example Peter.getTotalWage***
>
> ```
> System.out.println(Peter.getTickets() * (Peter.getWage()));
> ```

My issue is when it comes to multiplying int with double, I've tried something like this but can't seem to get it working as I know it is wrong (probably completely wrong to be honest):

```
}

public double totalWage(int tickets, double wage) {
    int i = tickets;
    Double d2=Double.valueOf(i);
    double sum = d2 * wage;

    return sum;
}
```

Right now I have two classes.
If you can help us identify how to go about doing this that'll be great!

Comment: `public double getTotalWage() { return this.wage * this.tickets }` ? Also your organization seems a little off. `Peter` isn't a Job. `Peter` is the `Person` or `Employee` fulfilling a job perhaps. Might want to rename some stuff.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, not like `Peter`, because they can get be confused with class names, which starts in uppercase.

Comment: Do you have an error?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for money.

Organize your classes properly. Apparently you have:

- An employee with a wage rate
- A job whose cost is the number of tickets multiplied by the assigned employee's wage rate.

So you need an `Employee` class with a member variable for wage rate. And you need a `Job` class with an assigned `Employee` object, and a `getWageCost` method with this logic:

```
 BigDecimal cost = 
        this.employee                               // An `Employee` object is assigned to this `Job` object.
        .getWageRate()                              // The `Job` object asks the `Employee` object for its current wage rate.
        .multiply( 
            new BigDecimal( this.countOfTickets ) 
        )
        .setScale( 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN )     // Round to the penny using Banker’s Rounding.
;
```

Tip to students: Notice how working towards a simple clear problem description written down in plain English can lead naturally to a proper class design. Lesson learned: *Prose before code*.

## `BigDecimal`

For money, never use `double` or `Double`, `float` or `Float`. The [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) types [trade away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. Use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for fractional money.

```
BigDecimal wageRate = new BigDecimal( "1.55" ) ;
```

Multiply.

```
BigDecimal cost = this.employee.getWageRate().multiply( new BigDecimal( this.countOfTickets ) ) ;
```

But that line above fails to address the fractional penny (assuming this is United States dollars). So round to the penny or to the tenth or hundredth of a penny as directed by your accounting staff.

Round by calling the `setScale` method. Use the rounding method as directed by your accounting staff. Often in business matters that would be [*Banker's Rounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). So to the line above we should add a call to `setScale` with the number of digits (2 for whole pennies of US Dollar) and the typing of rounding.

```
BigDecimal cost = this.employee.getWageRate().multiply( new BigDecimal( this.countOfTickets ) ).setScale( 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ) ;
```

The code above is logic on the `Job` class. Notice how it reaches into the `Employee` object to obtain the current wage rate for that worker.

## Example code

Here is complete example code.

```
Employee alice = new Employee( "Alice" , "EMP00013" , new BigDecimal( "1.55" ) );
Job whateverJob = new Job( alice , 100 , "whatever" , UUID.randomUUID() );
BigDecimal wagesCostForWhateverJob = whateverJob.getWageCost();

System.out.println( "whateverJob: " + whateverJob + " costs " + wagesCostForWhateverJob );
```

> whateverJob: Job{ employee=Employee{ name='Alice' | employeeId='EMP00013' | wageRate=1.55 } | countOfTickets=100 | description='whatever' | id=b4e397b3-e02e-42be-b117-622cee96a192 } costs 155.00

### `Employee.java`

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Employee
{
    // ---------|  Member vars  |----------------------------------
    private String name, employeeId;
    private BigDecimal wageRate;

    // ---------|  Constructors  |----------------------------------
    public Employee ( String name , String employeeId , BigDecimal wageRate )
    {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        this.employeeId = Objects.requireNonNull( employeeId );
        this.wageRate = Objects.requireNonNull( wageRate );
    }

    // ---------|  Accessors  |----------------------------------

    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmployeeId ( )
    {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getWageRate ( )
    {
        return wageRate;
    }

    // ---------|  Object  |----------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Employee employee = ( Employee ) o;
        return getEmployeeId().equals( employee.getEmployeeId() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getEmployeeId() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Employee{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | employeeId='" + employeeId + '\'' +
                " | wageRate=" + wageRate +
                " }";
    }
}
```

### `Job.java`

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Job
{
    // ---------|  Member vars  |----------------------------------
    private Employee employee;
    private Integer countOfTickets;
    private String description;
    private UUID id;


    // ---------|  Constructors  |----------------------------------

    public Job ( Employee employee , Integer countOfTickets , String description , UUID id )
    {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.countOfTickets = countOfTickets;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
    }


    // ---------|  Accessors  |----------------------------------

    public Employee getEmployee ( )
    {
        return employee;
    }

    public Integer getCountOfTickets ( )
    {
        return countOfTickets;
    }

    public String getDescription ( )
    {
        return description;
    }

    public UUID getId ( )
    {
        return id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getWageCost ( )
    {
        BigDecimal cost = this.employee.getWageRate().multiply( new BigDecimal( this.countOfTickets ) ).setScale( 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN );
        return cost;
    }


    // ---------|  Object  |----------------------------------


    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Job job = ( Job ) o;
        return getId().equals( job.getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Job{ " +
                "employee=" + employee +
                " | countOfTickets=" + countOfTickets +
                " | description='" + description + '\'' +
                " | id=" + id +
                " }";
    }
}
```

In real work, if `Job::getWageCost` would be called very very often, we *might* consider [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) the result. We could add a member variable to hold the result. But avoid falling into the trap of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score -1):

I played around with the code a bit; maybe this helps?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Job jobOne = new Job (100, 1.55);
        Person p1 = new Person("Peter Williams");
        double jobOnePay = jobOne.getTotal();
        p1.setWage(jobOnePay);
        System.out.println(p1.getName() + " gets paid: " + p1.getSetWage());

    }
}

class Job{
    private int tickets;
    private double wage;

    Job(int tickets, double wage) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
        this.wage = wage;
    }
    double getTotal(){
        return tickets*wage; 
    }

}


class Person{
    private String name;
    private double setWage;

    Person(String name){
        this.name = name;

    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void setWage(double setWage) {
        this.setWage = setWage;
    }

    double getSetWage() {
        return setWage;
    }
}
```

Output: "Peter Williams gets paid: 155.0"

Comment: Why you call getTickets() and getWage() if you have direct access to the attributes?

Comment: not sure tbh, but you're right
    double getTotal(){
        return tickets*wage;
    }